# Should a "==" implementation in Ruby check the type?

Tags: ruby, equality

I want to implement `==` for a ruby class. I can do

```
def ==(o)
  o.respond_to?(:id) && self.id == o.id
end
```

**or**

```
def ==(o)
  o.is_a?(Foo) && self.id == o.id
end
```

According to [this](http://www.wellho.net/mouth/985_Equality-in-Ruby-eql-and-equal-.html) article, it seems that the former would make more sense. If I was implementing `eql?` then I would do the latter. Is this correct?

Comment: `==` doesn't *mean* that it has to transcend types even if `eql?` has a more specific requirement. However, it might be useful that it is more structually-based, as shown.

Comment: @pst Are you saying using `respond_to?` is ok?

Comment: What is `id` in this scenario? Is it the same as Object#object_id or is it an active record id or an accessor to an instance variable?

Comment: @AmirRaminfar If you wish to allow `==` to be applied structurally, then yes. That being said, with the exception of something like `ostruct`, I can not readily think of a need... but object equality *can* cross-cut types. Just make sure the semantics are defined. (FWIW: I have been treating `.id` as `.x` in my head; that is, not related to the object ID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you're comparing to an arbitrary object or one of a specific type. The second form is specific, the first generic.

In your case you're probably fine with the specific form. Generic comparisons are only relevant when the object you're comparing with can be converted or interpreted as something that can match. Using `id` seems way too open ended. This would imply that Foo 10 and Bar 10 are equivalent when they might be drawn from completely different sources.

Comment: Right. I guess `.id` was a bad example. My class actually checks for `.job_id`